# Postgresql - Reducing rows to one if a condition is met

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that returns a series of objects. This is a small section of an example result (in JSON):

Query:

```
SELECT id, starttime, endtime, duration, type FROM things
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "starttime": "2016-09-15T03:27:09",
    "endtime": "2016-09-15T03:31:43",
    "duration": 274,
    "type": "bad"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "starttime": "2016-09-15T03:26:48",
    "endtime": "2016-09-15T03:27:09",
    "duration": 20,
    "status": "good"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "starttime": "2016-09-15T03:19:46",
    "endtime": "2016-09-15T03:26:48",
    "duration": 422,
    "status": "bad"
},
```

I am trying to exclude anything less than 30 seconds - this is simple enough. However I also need to combine the top two together - their durations combined, the `starttime` with id 1's `starttime` and `endttime` as id 3's `endtime`. So this:

```
{
    "starttime": "2016-09-15T03:19:46",
    "endtime": "2016-09-15T03:31:43",
    "duration": 696,
    "status": "bad"
},
```

Is this possible in Postgres/SQL? I think I could figure something out in Java/C# but would rather do it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 1 THEN s.starttime END) as starttime,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk = 2 THEN s.endtime END) as endtime,
       SUM(s.duration) as dur,
       --You didn't say which status you want
FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.id) as rnk
    FROM things t 
    WHERE t.duration >= 30) s
WHERE s.rnk < 3
```